# Sencha labelWidth is set with !important in inline style - how to change it from css

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

Why does sencha touch puts !important directive inside inline style attribute? There are now way to change width from css in this case.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you add a labelWidth attribute to the field if you want to override it afterwards.

Remove the `labelWidth` from your field's config, add a `cls` attribute and then customize your field only in the CSS.

Comment: by default labelWidth = 40% so it will be there anyway